# Accessing a server as localhost?

Tags: linux, ssh, localhost

I use ssh keys to access a server at lets say 200.200.200.200. It works fine. How can i access that server in my host as 127.0.0.1?
I have tried my best but couldn't make it work.

Comment: I mean if i put in browser 127.0.0.1, it should open up 200.200.200.200. I saw someone doing it and i want to know how.

Comment: Is this just one one machine, or several? If just one, you could modify your hosts file to redirect 127.0.0.1 to 200.200.200.200, but this could have unintended consequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally do this via port forwarding so you forward the remote port (the one from the server) that you are interested in to your local machine. Then you can access it via 127.0.0.1:

Example tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

In putty it is also straight forward:
http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html

You could also modify your local hosts file to point to this server but that often causes hick ups with local services.

Comment: Yes exactly, i got the port forwarded too, lets say 5555. But do i need a live ssh/telnet connection in order to open up 127.0.0.1 in the browser?

Comment: Yes of course, that's the deal because the tunnel is created by ssh :-) Then you enter http://127.0.0.1:5555 in your browser

Comment: Thank you so much carsten.
Also, can you tell me by what linux command can i see the forwarded port?

Comment: I would assume that you know the port because you start ssh. If you list your running processes (ps ax) you can see the parameters that have been passed to ssh. And in the worst case you can use netstat -an to see active connections.

Comment: but i am still unable to access it. cannot find the server

Comment: I will need some more details about your specific setup in order to answer. We can also discuss separately in a chat

Comment: That would be awesome but i think i don't have enough repute to chat. How else can i contact you?

Comment: Just add the steps that you have done to your question and I will have a look at it.